# How to upload my local maven projects into Github

Tags: eclipse, maven, github

I have searched a lot for this question, while most of the questions & answers are just for the simple maven projects, while for me, there are different folders in my maven project.
Please take a look of my project structure.
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd2aZ.png)

Now I have a project, a parent maven project, a common maven project and a manager maven project. 
"common" and "manager" are depending on parent and under "manager", there are five maven models, "dao" is depending on "pojo", "interface" is depending on "dao", "service" id depending on "interface" and "pojo", "web" is depending on "service".

I am quite struggled for uploading my project into GitHub. Most of the answers I've searched is for single and simple maven projects uploading to GitHub.

I am using eclipse mars 2.

Can anyone do me a favor?

I am quite thanks.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the [EGit tutorial](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/egit-tutorial/) if not enough, consider the command line, for uploading *all* your maven modules into *one* GitHub repo:

```
cd /path/to/your/main/pom.xml/folder
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "maven project"
git remote add origin https://github.com/<me>/<myrepo>
git push -u origin master
```

Then in Eclipse, a simple Team/Share will allow Eclipse to recognize your Git repo.